# how can I set (add) a label to a jenkins node from itself (powershell windows 2017)

Tags: powershell, jenkins

how can I set (add) a label to a jenkins node from itself (powershell windows 2017) ?

I have no access to jenkins admin mode from https GUI. (that should be the standard procedure to do so).

I have both :
access to the node I need to use as remote powershell console (administrator)
access to master jenkins ssh linux account (root)

here I would like to add another label to the client node from one of thoses CLI's.

Jenkins officials neither googling permit me to find a procedure to do so.

how can I do that ? (So I can build a script around that after to make it all).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative method, I had to change it in its own xml file

as

```
<label>label addmynewlabel</label>
```

then restarted jenkinsclient (useless ?)
& restart jenkins service  on jenkins main server